# Controls in Angular break when configuration options come from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that will return my some config options for an `ng-grid`.  The getGridOptions function takes the name of the controller it's used on and returns the correct set of options (only one shown here for brevity).

service for ng-grid options:

```
angular.module('services').service('GridOptionsService',function(){

    var documents = {
        data: 'myData',
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter:true,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: {
            pageSizes: [50,100,200],
            pageSize: 50,
            currentPage: 1
        },
        filterOptions:  {
            filterText: '',
            useExternalFilter: false
        },
        enableCellEdit: false,
        enableColumnReordering: true,
        enablePinning: false,
        showGroupPanel: false,
        groupsCollapsedByDefault: true,
        enableColumnResize: true,
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {field:'docId', displayName:'Document ID', cellTemplate: NgGridDomUtil.toLink('#/documents/{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}')},
            {field:'docTags', displayName:'Tags'},
            {field:'lastSaveDate', displayName:'Last saved'},
            {field:'documentVersion', displayName:'Version', width: 120},
            {field:'busDocId', displayName:'Customer Doc ID'},
            {field:'markedForDelete', displayName:'Deleted', width: 120, cellTemplate: NgGridDomUtil.toCheckbox('{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}')}]
    };

    var gridOptionManager = {
        documents: documents

    }
    return {
        getGridOptions: function(controllerName){
            return gridOptionManager[controllerName];
        }

    }
})
```

The NgGridDomUtil class just makes it easier to style things on the grid:

```
var NgGridDomUtil = (function(){
    var toLink = function(href){
    var html = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-href= "'+href+'" class="ngCellLink"><span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span></a></div>'
    return html;
}
var toCheckbox = function(_selected){
    var html = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><input type="checkbox" ng-change="console.log('+"TEST"+')" ng-model="COL_FIELD"  ng-input="COL_FIELD"' + (_selected ? 'selected' : '') + ' /></div>'
    return html
}
return {
    toLink: toLink,
    toCheckbox: toCheckbox
}
})();
```

My problem is what when I use the GridOptionsService to retrieve the data, the data is still presented to the grid correctly, but the text filtering no longer works and the paging is broken.  However, the `selectedFilterOption` still works.

controller:

```
angular.module('controllers').controller('Repository', ['$scope', 'DataContext','GridOptionsService','$http', function($scope, DataContext,GridOptionsService,$http) {
    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: '',
        useExternalFilter: false
    };
    $scope.totalServerItems =0;
    $scope.pagingOptions ={
        pageSizes: [5,10,100],
        pageSize: 5,
        currentPage: 1
    }
    //filter!
    $scope.dropdownOptions = [{
        name: 'Show all'

    },{
        name: 'Show active'
    },{
        name: 'Show trash'
    }];
    //default choice for filtering is 'show active'
    $scope.selectedFilterOption = $scope.dropdownOptions[1];


    //three stage bool filter
    $scope.customFilter = function(data){
        var tempData = [];
        angular.forEach(data,function(item){
            if($scope.selectedFilterOption.name === 'Show all'){
                tempData.push(item);
            }
            else if($scope.selectedFilterOption.name ==='Show active' && !item.markedForDelete){
                tempData.push(item);
            }
            else if($scope.selectedFilterOption.name ==='Show trash' && item.markedForDelete){
                tempData.push(item);
            }
        });
        return tempData;
    }



    //grabbing data
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function(pageSize, page,  searchText){
        var data;
        if(searchText){
            var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
            DataContext.getDocuments().success(function(largeLoad){
                //filter the data when searching
                data = $scope.customFilter(largeLoad).filter(function(item){
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                })
                $scope.setPagingData($scope.customFilter(data),page,pageSize);
            })
        }
        else{
            DataContext.getDocuments().success(function(largeLoad){
                var testLargeLoad = $scope.customFilter(largeLoad);
                //filter the data on initial page load when no search text has been entered
                $scope.setPagingData(testLargeLoad,page,pageSize);
            })
        }
    };
    //paging
    $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
        var pagedData = data.slice((page -1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        //filter the data for paging
        $scope.myData = $scope.customFilter(pagedData);
        $scope.myData = pagedData;
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
//        if(!$scope.$$phase){
//            $scope.$apply();
//        }
    }

    //watch for filter option change, set the data property of gridOptions to the newly filtered data
    $scope.$watch('selectedFilterOption',function(){
        var data = $scope.customFilter($scope.myData);
        $scope.myData = data;
        $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
        $scope.setPagingData($scope.myData,$scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,$scope.pagingOptions.pageSize);
    })
    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions',function(newVal, oldVal){
        $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,$scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,$scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        $scope.setPagingData($scope.myData,$scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,$scope.pagingOptions.pageSize);
    },true)


    $scope.message ="This is a message";
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter:true,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        enableCellEdit: true,
        enableColumnReordering: true,
        enablePinning: true,
        showGroupPanel: true,
        groupsCollapsedByDefault: true,
        enableColumnResize: true
    }
    $scope.gridOptions = GridOptionsService.getGridOptions('documents');
    //get the data on page load
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
}]);
```

The grid options that I have hard coded into the controller are the same as the ones returned from the service.  What I don't understand is why the grid renders, the dropdown filter works, but the paging is broken, only when the options for the grid come from a service?  But it works as expected if it's hard coded into the controller.

EDIT: If someone can more eloquently state my problem, feel free to edit the title.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know how the ngGrid is implemented, but a common pitfall I do know that exist in many directives, is they expect their configurations to be ready as soon as they're initialized. Meaning that instead of watching the configuration object, they assume it exists and use it directly in the link\controller functions which runs as soon as they're created.

If this is indeed the case, a quick workaround to the problem is initializing the directive only when you have the configuration object. Let's say you pass on the configuration object through the variable 'options' on your scope, you'll then write something like:

```
<!-- If options exists on your scope, it means you fetched it from the server -->
<div ng-if="options">
    <div ng-grid ng-grid-options="options"></div>
</div>
```

Again, I'm not familiar with ngGrid or its usage, this is just an educated guess, take the conclusions and apply them on the correct API.

Comment: that was a good guess, but doesn't work in my case.  Did learn a little, though :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but one possible issue is that you are overwriting an object that is on the $scope.  This can break the two way binding.  For a quick test try

```
    $scope.grid = {
        Options: {
            data: 'myData',
            enablePaging: true,
            showFooter:true,
            totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
            pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
            filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
            enableCellEdit: true,
            enableColumnReordering: true,
            enablePinning: true,
            showGroupPanel: true,
            groupsCollapsedByDefault: true,
            enableColumnResize: true
        }
   }
   $scope.grid.Options = GridOptionsService.getGridOptions('documents');
```

You would need to update the grid options in the directives attribute as well of course.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the controller functions for filtering and paging use the options defined on the controller `$scope`, but the ng-grid UI is not bound to those objects.

The controller methods for filtering and paging use `$scope.pagingOptions` as the data source. However, the ng-grid UI is bound to `$scope.gridOptions.pagingOptions`. When you create the `$scope.gridOptions` explicitly in the controller, `$scope.gridOptions.pagingOptions` refers to the same object as `$scope.gridOptions`, so making changes in the UI will change the value used in the controller functions.

However, when `$scope.gridOptions` is assigned using the service, the service is creating new `pagingOptions`, so there is no connection between `$scope.gridOptions.pagingOptions` and `$scope.pagingOptions`. Making changes in the UI will not change the values used in the controller functions.

The same is true for `filterOptions`.

One way to resolve the issue is

```
$scope.gridOptions = GridOptionsService.getGridOptions('documents');
$scope.pagingOptions = $scope.gridOptions.pagingOptions
$scope.filterOptions = $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions
```